# Exact match and fuzziness...What is the good way?

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, fuzzy-search, exact-match

i was invert many hours  trying found the best way to create and autocomplete that support a multilanguaje seach of cities. (ES/EN), fuzzieness and get priority for exact match (show this at top of results) but i cant find a good way to make this task.

My current solution work very well in many cases, but when I to find for Roma the first option is "Iasi-East Romania, romania"  and Roma italy is the thirty function (is an exact match)

Result Json:

```
[{"_index":"destinations","_type":"doc","_id":"_X80XWcBn2nzTu98N7_F","_score":75.50012,"_source":{"destination_name_en":"Iasi-East Romania","destination_name_es":"Iasi-East Romania","destination_name_pt":"Iasi-East Romania","country_code":"RO","country_name":"ROMANIA","destination_id":7953,"popularity":"0"}},{"_index":"destinations","_type":"doc","_id":"7380XWcBn2nzTu98OMZl","_score":73.116455,"_source":{"destination_name_en":"La Romana","destination_name_es":"La Romana","destination_name_pt":"La Romana","country_code":"DO","country_name":"DOMINICAN REPUBLIC","destination_id":2816,"popularity":"0"}},{"_index":"destinations","_type":"doc","_id":"1X80XWcBn2nzTu98OMZl","_score":71.4391,"_source":{"_index":"destinations","_type":"doc","_id":"8H80XWcBn2nzTu98OMZl","_score":52.018818,"_source":{"destination_name_en":"Rome","destination_name_es":"Roma","destination_name_pt":"Roma","country_code":"IT","country_name":"ITALY","destination_id":6338,"popularity":"0"}}]
```

Right now this is my best solution..

Mapping:

```
'settings' => [ 
                'analysis' => [     
                    'filter' => [
                        'autocomplete_filter' => [
                            "type"=> "edge_ngram",
                            "min_gram"=> 1,
                            "max_gram"=> 20,

                        ]
                    ],
                    'analyzer' => [
                        'autocomplete' => [
                            "type" => "custom",
                            'tokenizer' => "standard",
                            'filter' => ['lowercase', 'asciifolding', 'autocomplete_filter'],
                        ]
                    ],

                ],   
            ],
            'mappings' =>[
                'doc' => [
                    "properties"=> [
                        "destination_name_en"=> [
                           "type"=> "text",
                           "analyzer"=> "autocomplete",
                           "search_analyzer"=> "standard",

                        ],
                        "destination_name_es"=> [
                           "type"=> "text",
                           "analyzer"=> "autocomplete",
                           "search_analyzer"=> "standard",
                        ],
                        "destination_name_pt"=> [
                           "type"=> "text",
                           "analyzer"=> "autocomplete",
                           "search_analyzer"=> "standard",
                        ],
                        "popularity"=> [
                           "type"=> "integer",
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

Search:

```
'query' => [
                "bool" => [
                    "should" => [   
                         [
                            "multi_match"=>[
                                "query"=>$text,
                                "fields"=>[
                                   "destination_name_*"
                                ],
                                "type"=>"most_fields",
                                "boost" => 2
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "multi_match"=>[
                                "query"=>$text,
                                "fields"=>[
                                   "destination_name_*"
                                ],
                                "fuzziness" => "1",
                                "prefix_length"=> 2                                   
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

Also, i want add boost to specific destination using her popularity value.

I hope that someone can guide me with an example or direction of which way to go.

I would appreciate it very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probleme is that when you search `roma`, Iasi-East Romania the first result since it contains roma in all language. But `roma` is only matching for `Rome` in ES/PT/IT and not for EN.

So if you want to boost exact matching your need to index your city name in another field without autocompletion (for all language) and add a new clause in the should on those field.

example for the mapping :

```
 "properties"=> [
        "destination_name_en"=> [
                "type"=> "text",
                "analyzer"=> "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer"=> "standard",
                "fields": => [
                    "exact" => [
                        "type"=> "text",
                        "analyzer"=> "standard", // you could use a more fancy analyzer here
                    ]

                ]
        ],
....
```

and in the query :

```
'query' => [
                "bool" => [
                    "should" => [   
                         [
                            "multi_match"=>[
                                "query"=>$text,
                                "fields"=>[
                                   "destination_name_*"
                                ],
                                "type"=>"most_fields",
                                "boost" => 2
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "multi_match"=>[
                                "query"=>$text,
                                "fields"=>[
                                   "destination_name_*"
                                ],
                                "fuzziness" => "1",
                                "prefix_length"=> 2                                   
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "multi_match"=>[
                                "query"=>$text,
                                "type"=>"most_fields" 
                                "fields"=>[
                                   "destination_name_*.exact"
                                ],
                                "boost" => 2 
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

Could you try something like that and keep us posted ?

Answer (score 0):

this work like a charm!. Now I can obtain rome in the first results and also accepts mistakes at end of the word. Romi return too Rome in the first result.

Now i'm trying to boost the results by the popularity field(i have two romes, Rome-italy and rome-australy) and i want to boost some populars citys in the world.

I'm using the function score but this get me very strange results.

This is my current code:

```
'query' => [
                'function_score' => [
                    'field_value_factor' => [
                        'field' => 'popularity',
                    ],
                    "score_mode" => "multiply",
                    'query' => [
                        "bool" => [
                            "should" => [   
                                 [
                                    "multi_match"=>[
                                        "query"=>$text,
                                        "fields"=>[
                                           "destination_name_*"
                                        ],
                                        "type"=>"most_fields",
                                        "boost" => 2
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [
                                    "multi_match"=>[
                                        "query"=>$text,
                                        "fields"=>[
                                           "destination_name_*"
                                        ],
                                        "fuzziness" => "1",
                                        "prefix_length"=> 2                                   
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [
                                    "multi_match"=>[
                                        "query"=>$text,
                                        "fields"=>[
                                           "destination_name_*.exact"
                                        ],
                                        "boost" => 2                                   
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
```

Any sugestions?

PD: Thank you very much for the help. from now I give you the best answer because you have already solved the main problem

Comment: could you open a new question for your function score problem? The SO policy is to have focused questions for further readability. I will gladly help you afterward. An d BTW could you add to your question the values of popularity field and the strange results you obtain?

Comment: Hello Pierre, I create the new question in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625282/boost-results-by-integer-field
Thanks for all!